# What if I want to dispatch MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP when un-clicking only some objects, not all of them?

Tags: actionscript-3

What if I want to dispatch MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP when un-clicking only some objects, not all of them? I mean, when I add eventListener that listens for MOUSE_UP, it's dispatched (thought with different targets) every time I un-click anywhere, if you understand what I mean. How can I "fix" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you listen for MOUSE_UP events on the stage, or some other container that holds a lot of different objects that can be clicked. If you want to get only some of those Events, listen only to those objects specifically, so add eventListeners to all of those objects separately.
Another option is to check the `target` of the Event, to find out which object sent the MOUSE_UP Event.

And another option is to use `mouseEnabled=false` on any object you don't want to send MOUSE_UP Events.

Post some code and I may post some too...

Comment: Actually, I'm adding listener to the object from inside, like `this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, doSmth)`. I set my `target` to `mouseEnabled=false` so it cannot receive any MouseEvents, that's the problem. Is there any other way?